# how to search in google from python?

Tags: python

i'm trying to make a script and for that script i need python to search in google for me is there a way to do that? like i'm telling python to search coffee and he will find it on google and open a tab the in that tab the search word is coffee?
i've tried the serpapi but it didn't work is there any other way?
this is the code i tried just to check and it didn't work i took it straight out of their official website

```
from serpapi.google_search_results import GoogleSearchResults
client = GoogleSearchResults({"q": "coffee", "location": "Austin,Texas", "api_key": "secretKey"})
result = client.get_dict()
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "it didn't work".

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, as you changed the question in such a way that it, essentially, invalidated the answer which you have accepted. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use module [google](https://pypi.org/project/google/).

Example:

```
from googlesearch import search
query = "Apple"
for res in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=2):
    print(res)
```

Comment: is there a way that i can make search what im saying him to inside google translate?

Comment: like that if i will write in google what is the mening of any word in any laguge the first thing that will come up is google translate is there to just search in google and not search for a url?

Comment: i put the code in the main thing is there a way to make it just search in google and not open a tab?